# Function not working on live server but every thing is fine on localhost

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am using a class to add featured images to the taxonomy terms , followed the tutorial on 
http://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/

this is the code i used inside my services.php (file for CPT )

```
require_once("Tax-meta-class/Tax-meta-class.php");

/*
* configure taxonomy custom fields
*/
$config = array(
   'id' => 'demo_meta_box',                         // meta box id, unique per meta box
   'title' => 'Demo Meta Box',                      // meta box title
   'pages' => array('packages_type'),               // taxonomy name, accept categories, post_tag and custom taxonomies
   'context' => 'normal',                           // where the meta box appear: normal (default), advanced, side; optional
   'fields' => array(),                             // list of meta fields (can be added by field arrays)
   'local_images' => false,                         // Use local or hosted images (meta box images for add/remove)
   'use_with_theme' => false                        //change path if used with theme set to true, false for a plugin or anything else for a custom path(default false).
);
$my_meta = new Tax_Meta_Class($config);
//Image field
$my_meta->addImage('heading',array('name'=> 'Heading '));
$my_meta->addImage('image',array('name'=> 'Image '));


/*
* Don't Forget to Close up the meta box deceleration
*/
//Finish Taxonomy Extra fields Deceleration
$my_meta->Finish();
```

and then i used this code to get theimages

```
<?php $custom_terms= get_terms('packages_type');    
              $count=1;        
              $int=1;          
              foreach($custom_terms as $term):
              $heading = get_tax_meta($term->term_id,'heading');
              $image = get_tax_meta($term->term_id,'image');                  
            ?>  
<img src="<?php echo $heading['url']; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="">
```

Every thing works fine on localhost but when i moved the site to live server i am unable to get the images and get the warning under image tag -**illegal string offset 'url'** .
What is it that i am doing wrong

Comment: Sorry. But feeling helpless as my problem doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

amritanshu you not add id

```
$my_meta->addText('text_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Text '));

'YOUR-FIELD_ID'
```

Print Command JUST add that line

```
$saved_data = get_tax_meta($term_id,'YOUR-FIELD-ID');
```

echo $saved_data;

Comment: i have added the id                                                       $my_meta->addImage('heading',array('name'=> 'Heading '));
$my_meta->addImage('image',array('name'=> 'Image '));

Comment: @amritanshu do you use Prifix? $saved_data = get_tax_meta($term_id,'PRIFIX-YOUR-FIELD-ID');

Comment: no there is no prifix being used in the tut. plus i am also not using it coz there is just 'heading' being used in $my_meta->addImage('heading',array('name'=> 'Heading '));      so i am also using 'heading' only in       $heading = get_tax_meta($term->term_id,'heading');           I think you are confusing it with tutorial for the meta boxes where prefix is being used..Any ways thanks